# How connect Azure function using managed identity with Azure Service bus

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I am creating an Azure function using Azure portal. I added trigger and trying to add connection to service bus ( I am adding **Azure service bus topic trigger**). When I try to add connection string I am only seeing one option called `RootManagedSharedAccessKey`. ***I do not want to connect using shared access key. Instead I want to use managed identity.*** But that option is not at all available. See attached image fore more information. I have already added Managed Identity to Azure function app.

How can I configure function to use managed identity ? I am not deploying\creating function using Visual Studio. I am just using Azure Portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a managed identity and you need to add`Azure role assignments` by clicking on `add role assignment` as below:

1. Azure Service Bus Data Receiver
2. Azure Service Bus Data Owner

[image]

Now in `Service Bus` also, You need to assign the same roles whichever given for your `managed identity` as below:

```
Service Bus ->Access Control(IAM) -> Add role assignment
```

[image]

After assigning the managed identities, it should reflect in your Service Bus as shown here.

[image]

Now create a function in function app by triggering the Azure Service Bus Topic Trigger with the help of managed identity.

[image]

[image]

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2#configure-your-service-bus-trigger-with-a-managed-identity)

Comment: @Jahnavi: I have disabled shared access key. I do not want communication to happen using shared access key. Instead i want to use managed identity.

Comment: @OpenStack I have given the answer as per your request. Kindly check and let me know if it works and I have used managed identity only but not enabled shared access key.

Comment: Under the `ServiceBusConnection` dropdown, I only see `RootManageSharedAccessKey` option. Manage Identity is not appearing.